# Cannot set a default value for MUI Autocomplete with Formik when options are being fetched with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm trying to use Autocomplete with Formik while fetching options with a useEffect hook and saving the options array through useState. It's been integrated and seems to be working except until I tried to set a default value. When I set a default value directly, the page shows the set value but it disappears and shows the field empty again as soon as I refresh the page.

If I set it with formik state inside `intialValues` then the string inside `TextField` shows `undefined` and the console shows this message:

```
Material-UI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `211`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

I am using `useEffect` to fetch the options array but for simplicity adding an array directly in codesandbox.

Here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-colden-9x75v4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your mentioned sandbox didn't run. Check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-coepnz?file=/src/App.js). I have used mui 5

Comment: This is working but as soon as I remove `multiple` and `limitTags={1}` props, the string shows undefined.

Comment: I have modified the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-6gcu9i?file=/src/App.js) for a single value. First, you have to filter out the value and then set it. The previous example was for multi-select and multi-select uses an array instead of single object value

Comment: First of all, thank you so much. I really appreciate you helping me out. Because of your modified example, I was able to solve this in theory and figure out the problem. Check out my modified [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-colden-9x75v4?file=/src/App.js). It works when I have the projects array as static and preloaded in memory. But as soon as I comment out the projects array from outside and add useState (line: 17) and useEffect (line: 23-30), the field gets empty again. I need to use useEffect because I am fetching the projects array to populate the dropdown from an API.

Comment: welcome, just add `enableReinitialize: true` in useFormik https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-boyd-ogh3lv?file=/src/App.js:1047-1077

Comment: Thanks again Usama. Can you check this one out? I am trying to implement masking in an MUI TextField with react-hook-form but having trouble with helper text. Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb). Much appreciated again!